# MySQL Select, Show one row with several values on columns

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to show one row per product, but each product has several values.
This is what I'm trying:

```
select pr.ID_PRO, pr.NOMBRE_PRODUCTO, img.DIRECCION, m.MARCA_NOMBRE from 
productos pr INNER JOIN 
img_pro img ON pr.ID_PRO = img.FOR_PRO INNER JOIN 
mm_productos_marca pm ON pm.ID_PRO = pr.ID_PRO INNER JOIN 
marca m ON m.ID_MAR = pm.ID_MAR;
```

Result:

```
+--------+-----------------+---------------------------+--------------+
| ID_PRO | NOMBRE_PRODUCTO | DIRECCION                 | MARCA_NOMBRE |
+--------+-----------------+---------------------------+--------------+
|      1 | asdasd          | images/discos-esmeril.jpg | ABRATOOLS    |
|      1 | asdasd          | images/lol.png            | ABRATOOLS    |
|      2 | 123qwe1         | images/images.jpg         | ABRATOOLS    |
|      2 | 123qwe1         | images/images.jpg         | BRAND        |
+--------+-----------------+---------------------------+--------------+
```

Desire result:

```
+--------+-----------------+---------------------------+--------------+
| ID_PRO | NOMBRE_PRODUCTO | DIRECCION                 | MARCA_NOMBRE |
+--------+-----------------+---------------------------+--------------+
|      1 | asdasd          | images/discos-esmeril.jpg | ABRATOOLS    |
|        |                 | images/lol.png            |              |
+--------+-----------------+---------------------------+--------------+
|      2 | 123qwe1         | images/images.jpg         | ABRATOOLS    |
|        |                 |                           | BRAND        |
+--------+-----------------+---------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: You're looking for [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: @DipenShah http://prntscr.com/88rrf7 This is the result.

Comment: Isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are ok with coma separated `DIRECCION` values(in my opinion that is the best solution), then you can use following query

```
    select ID_PRO,NOMBRE_PRODUCTO,group_concat(DIRECCION)as 
        DIRECCION,MARCA_NOMBRE from tab1 group by NOMBRE_PRODUCTO
          order by id_pro
```

Coma separated values makes processing much easier